# Euclidean construction of sine curve

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given a point a circle with the point as its center is a set of points equidistant from the point.

Similarly given 2 points an ellipse is a set of points each with equal sums of distances from the two points.

A sine is a convergent real valued infinite series of real numbers. Plotting it in a Cartesian coordinate system interpreting its  value as a coordinate on the y axis one gets a sine curve.

But was there a way to plot out an equivalent curve in a pre Descartes era, without any coordinates that is?

Answer (score 1):

How to generate a sine curve with a wooden cylinder, paint and paper:

1. Cut the cylinder obliquely to the axis, forming a slanted elliptical "top".
2. Paint the remaining lateral surface.
3. Roll the painted cylinder onto the paper and note the boundary.